# How do I use the "ANY" filter in conjucntion with the "<<=" operator in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with INET columns and want to run a query filtering all entries which are in any of a set of given networks. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   cidr INET
);
```

In SQL I can write the following:

```
SELECT cidr FROM foo WHERE cidr <<= ANY '{"192.168.1.0/24", "192.168.3.0/24"}';
```

I found [the "any" operator in SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Any) which works well for standard operators, but cannot get it to work with the `<<=` operator. How do I do that?

So I have something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import Any

query = session.query(Foo)
query = query.filter(Any(
    Foo.cidr,
    [ip_network('192.168.1.0/24'), ip_network('192.168.3.0/24')],
    operator=?  # <-- What do I need to put here?
))
```

Additionally, the model defines a custom type to adapt the "ip_network" type to the appropriate DB type. This change prevents me from using a `text` construct with bound params, so currently I have to resort to string concatenations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you can use [`custom_op`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.custom_op):

```
session.query(Foo).filter(Any(
    Foo.cidr,
    array([cast('192.168.1.0/24', INET), cast('192.168.3.0/24', INET)]),
    operator=custom_op("<<="),
))
```

But [`dialects.postgresql.Any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Any) is deprecated in favor of [`sql.expression.any_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.any_), which is more natural to use:

```
arr = array([cast('192.168.1.0/24', INET), cast('192.168.3.0/24', INET)])
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(arr)))
```

This renders SQL like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM foo 
WHERE foo.cidr <<= ANY (ARRAY[CAST(%(param_1)s AS INET), CAST(%(param_2)s AS INET)])
```

Comment: Thanks, using `Any` works, but using `any_` gives me the error: `can't adapt type 'Cast'`. I will accept this, as one of the two solutions works though. But I'm curious why `any_` does not work. I will also quickly put together a workable example and add it to the question.

Comment: I've added a new question which was in fact the reason why it did not work using `any_`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47811469/160665