# How can I adapt custom types in SQL Expression statements?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a custom type in application using the SQLAlchemy ORM mapper. For some complex queries I need to use the SQL expression module, but this makes handling of the custom types non-transparent. How can I tell SQLAlchemy to use my custom types for mapping when *not* using the ORM?

Below is a quick example demonstrating the problem.

Note that the first query works, but I have to manually cast it first to `str` in Python and next to `INET` for PostgreSQL even though I have my custom type defined.

I understand that the SQL expression module is unaware of the custom type as it is defined one layer above it in the ORM. But I wonder if there is no way I could wire that custom type somehow into the SQL layer making usage of types and values much more transparent. And additionally ensuring that any operation (clean-ups and so on) defined in the custom type are consistently applied no matter what layer of SA is being used.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import any_
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

Base = declarative_base()


class PgIpInterface(TypeDecorator):
    """
    A codec for :py:mod:`ipaddress` interfaces.
    """

    impl = INET

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return str(value) if value else None

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return ip_interface(value) if value else None

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        raise NotImplementedError('Not yet implemented')


class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example_table'
    cidr = Column(PgIpInterface, primary_key=True)


def execute(query):
    import logging
    LOG = logging.getLogger()
    try:
        print(query)
        print(query.all())
    except:
        LOG.exception('!!! failed')


engine = create_engine('postgresql://malbert@/malbert')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

ranges = [
    ip_interface('192.168.1.0/24'),
    ip_interface('192.168.3.0/24'),
]


# Query with manual casting
print(' Manual Casting via "str" '.center(80, '-'))
arr = array([cast(str(_), INET) for _ in ranges])
query1 = session.query(Network).filter(Network.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(arr)))
execute(query1)


print(' Manual Casting '.center(80, '-'))
arr = array([cast(_, INET) for _ in ranges])
query2 = session.query(Network).filter(Network.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(arr)))
execute(query2)


# Query without casting
print(' No Casting '.center(80, '-'))
query3 = session.query(Network).filter(Network.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(ranges)))
execute(query3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your second query work, simply cast to your custom type:

```
arr = array([cast(_, PgIpInterface) for _ in ranges])
```

To make your third query work, you need to go one level deeper, in `psycopg2`. `psycopg2` has [builtin support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#networking-data-types) for `ipaddress` types, but unfortunately it seems incomplete. (`ipaddress` types are converted to string without an explicit cast.)

```
register_ipaddress()  # register ipaddress handling globally
arr = [ip_interface('192.168.1.0/24'), ip_interface('192.168.3.0/24')]
session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(arr))).all()
```

This renders something like

```
WHERE foo.cidr <<= ANY (ARRAY['192.168.1.0/24', '192.168.3.0/24'])
```

which fails with a `operator does not exist: inet <<= text` error. Fortunately, it's easy to fix it; we'll just rewrite `register_ipaddress` ourselves:

```
import ipaddress

from psycopg2.extensions import (
    AsIs,
    new_array_type,
    new_type,
    register_adapter,
    register_type
)


def register_ipaddress():
    def cast_interface(s, cur=None):
        if s is None:
            return None
        return ipaddress.ip_interface(s)
    inet = new_type((869,), 'INET', cast_interface)
    ainet = new_array_type((1041,), 'INET[]', inet)

    def cast_network(s, cur=None):
        if s is None:
            return None
        return ipaddress.ip_network(s)
    cidr = new_type((650,), 'CIDR', cast_network)
    acidr = new_array_type((651,), 'CIDR[]', cidr)

    for caster in [inet, ainet, cidr, acidr]:
        register_type(caster)

    def adapt_interface(obj):
        return AsIs("'{}'::inet".format(obj))
    for t in [ipaddress.IPv4Interface, ipaddress.IPv6Interface]:
        register_adapter(t, adapt_interface)

    def adapt_network(obj):
        return AsIs("'{}'::cidr".format(obj))
    for t in [ipaddress.IPv4Network, ipaddress.IPv6Network]:
        register_adapter(t, adapt_network)
```

This will render your query like

```
WHERE foo.cidr <<= ANY (ARRAY['192.168.1.0/24'::inet, '192.168.3.0/24'::inet])
```

Note the difference between using

```
arr = array([ip_interface...])
```

and

```
arr = [ip_interface...]
```

In the former case, the array is processed by SQLAlchemy, so you'll get `n` bound parameters for `n` items in the list; in the latter case, the array is processed by `psycopg2`, so you'll get one bound parameter for the entire array.

Comment: Thank you. This works. But I think I will not implement it on the `psycopg` layer. The amount of added SLOC is not worth the trouble. But your first tip, casting to the custom type works like a charm. I tested both solutions though, and they both work. I will just edit the post, making it Python 3 compatible and adding the required `psycopg2` imports if someone else comes across this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For anyone wondering, here's a `psycopg2` [github issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/653) that closed this request for automated casting as won't-fix.

Comment: As yet another alternative, instead of patching `register_ipaddress` one could add explicit cast for the whole array: `Foo.cidr.op("<<=")(any_(cast(arr, postgresql.ARRAY(postgresql.CIDR)))))`

Comment: Warning: `register_ipaddress` comes with catastrophic implications on performance. In my case it results in at least 1000x slowdown when fetching models from DB (it appears to constantly invoke `ipaddress` methods on every loaded value).